# Update TinyMce Templates Plugin

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm trying to filter templates by clicking on buttons, I have three lists of templates and I want every button to show one of these lists in templates.

my try:

```
self.wysiwygConfig = {
    plugins: ['... template ...'],
    toolbar: '... | template | spellchecker | buttonA buttonB buttonC',
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.ui.registry.addButton('buttonA', {
            text: 'A',
            onAction: function () {
                //filter the list
                //doesn't work
                self.wysiwygConfig.templates = [];

                //also this doean't work
                UserFilterTemplates = [];

                //open the modal
                $('.tox-tbtn[title="Insert template"]').trigger("click");
            }
        });
        /* same for buttonB && buttonC */
    },
    templates: UserFilterTemplates.map(item => ({ title: item.Title, description: item.Description, content: item.Template }))
};
```

is there any way to filter or to reinitialize the templates?

Comment: See "Separating template definitions from TinyMCE config" here: https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-templates/

Comment: @NathanHawks thanks, but I don't think that there is exactly what I want.